# Putting event-dispatch thread on hold until Swing timer stops

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

I'm creating a program that plays a sequence of notes on a piano and then determines whether the user's clicks on the piano match what was just played. I got the program to play a sequence of notes automatically using a Swing timer, but I need it to wait until the sequence is done playing before it continues. Here's a simplified example of what I have now:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myProgram {

    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new AutoPlay());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                myProgram myProgram = new myProgram();
                System.out.println("Computer plays notes.");
                myProgram.compTurn();
                System.out.println("Your turn.");
            }
        });   
    }

    class AutoPlay implements ActionListener {

        int i = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Auto-played note.");
            i++;
            if (i == 2) timer.stop();
        }
    }

    // TODO - Play a melody for the user to repeat
    public void compTurn() {
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

"Your turn" prints too soon. If it helps, the point of the timer is to have the program trigger an audio note, update the piano graphic so you can see the pressed note, load up the next note that will be played, and repeat until the sequence is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variant of the observer pattern to be notified of when the timer is done. For instance a PropertyChangeListener would work nicely. For example...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyProg2 extends JPanel {
   public static final String TIMER_COMPLETE = "timer complete";
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
   private Timer timer;
   public MyProg2() {
      // TODO create GUI
   }

   public void playNotes() {
      if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
         return;
      }
      timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
      timer.start();
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      private int i = 0;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("Auto-played note.");
         i++;
         if (i == 2) {
            timer.stop();
            firePropertyChange(TIMER_COMPLETE, false, true);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      System.out.println("Starting program");
      MyProg2 mainPanel = new MyProg2();
      mainPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (MyProg2.TIMER_COMPLETE.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName()) && pcEvt.getNewValue() == Boolean.TRUE) {
               System.out.println("Your turn");
            }
         }
      });
      mainPanel.playNotes();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyProg2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Your solution worked. After studying it, though, I wonder: What is the advantage of your solution over just putting System.out.printin("Your turn") right after timer.stop() -- and not calling firePropertyChange at all?

Comment: @crayk: in a real program, you won't be just calling some println method but rather you will have one object waiting for another object to change state, and then respond to the change in state. You want the observed object to be as ignorant about the observer(s) as possible so that it can be used in any situation that might require it. The concept I'm espousing is [low or loose coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)), and it is a program characteristic to strive for to ease your code enhancement and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Disable user input options when the computer starts playing. Enable them when it is the users turn. Never disable the edt.